# Is it possible to configure WordPress's Core Files to accept duplicate Child Categories?

Tags: urls, directory

I am currently building a site structure, for an eCommerce site.  The shopping platform, is WooCommerce

As well as much research, I have spoken with many people, regarding best practices for URL structures.  Some common conclusions, include:

- Keep URLs to an absolute minimum, without losing context;
- Avoid duplicate directory references;
- Keep a URL as clean as possible, ensuring a logical hierarchy.

As such, I would like to create the following URL structures:

1. `www.example.com/parent-category-a/red`
2. `www.example.com/parent-category-b/red`

The problem I have, is that my current WordPress installation does not allow duplicate directory names.  If I create a duplicate directory name, it will prefix the Parent Category.  For example:

- 'www.example.com/parent-category-a/red'

... would become

- `www.example.com/parent-category-a/parent-category-a-red`

I know I could have `/red-[product name]` as a directory name but the product names are within contained within the `/parent-category/` directory.

Firstly, does anyone disagree with the notion that it would be okay to have duplicate directory names as long as they reside in different Parent Directories?

Assuming there are no SEO issues, in having duplicate directory names, how can I modify WordPress, to allow such duplicate Directory names?